# Cronjob is not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, cron

I would like to put in place some cronjobs for my website.

My actual cronjob is:
`4 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/domain/backup.php`

But it doesn't work.

- Mannually the cron job is working.
- With a service like `https://www.easycron.com` it's working too.

In `Terminal`, when I make `crontab -e`, I see my cronjob but it does not seem to run.

From where I can start my search to understand ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the contents of backup.php? @DamDam

Comment: First step, check /var/log/cron (or whatever it might be on your system) to verify if the cron daemon is even attempting to launch your job.

Comment: is your cron running? there will be a log in /var/log/syslog that should show the job being run - can you see it there? are there any CRON logs there?

Comment: Sure. Simple as `fopen("/var/www/domain/testfile.txt", "w")`

Comment: @AlexHowansky, when I make `nano /var/log/cron`, the file is empty.

Comment: Add `#!/usr/bin/php -q` at the top of the file before the `<?php` tag. Then set your cron as `4 * * * *  /var/www/domain/backup.php &> /dev/null`. Also make sure crontab is actually running.

Comment: @KasiaGogolek, is the file I have `Feb  1 17:00:01 domainname CRON[20059]: (root) CMD (php -f /var/www/domain/backup.php)`

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji: done. But the nothing new...

Comment: Try stopping and staring the cron service. `service cron stop` `service cron start`

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji: same again.

Comment: @DamDam seems like it's being run then - what were you expecting your script to do?

Comment: Actually I want to create a simple .txt file.

Comment: One problem I've had multiple times is if the cron script has to access files and there are relative paths in use. If you have any includes, be sure that you `chdir(basename(__FILE__))` so that you are sure the script is running from the current folder that the script is in.

Comment: Also, it might be worth it to create a test cron script to fire every minute that does something simple like: `<?php mail('youremail@domain','Testing Cron','test');`. If that cron script executes properly and you receive the email, you know the issue is with your backup script, not cronjobs.

Comment: Please note that running php scripts from cron may result in unexpected *working directory* for the script. When you run from command line, it works because you are in the correct working directory. However, cron may run it from a system directory your script has no write access to. Add the line to include `cd` to your desired destination and then `&& /usr/bin/php your-script.php`

Answer (score 0):

In my server, when setting up a php file to run, I only have to put: 
`4 * * * * php /var/www/domain/backup.php`. They run flawlessly. Works the same for my shell scripts as well with just `bash /directory/thisScript.sh`

I added this as an answer because my reputation score won't let me add comments yet.